# How to properly test float or double for quality and other comparisons

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, equality

Im having some problems with comparing real numbers stored as doubles.
I think the problems are most likely cause by rounding errors but im not sure.
How would be the best way to compare numbers stored as doubles and tested in linq ?

I get a time as a string from a 3rd party source.
This looks like it is seconds from the epoch
Converting it to real time im sure it is in seconds and not milliseconds.
I covert that to a double using
double Time = Convert.ToDouble("1549666889.6220000");
Then i use linq to extract from a list all the entries that encompass this time

```
Infos.Where(x => x.StartTime <= starttime                                                                 
&& x.EndTime >= starttime).OrderBy(x => x.StartTime).ToList();
```

and the results i get seem outside the comparison boundary i expected.
I expected the returned items are those that the time im testing for are between the start and end times of the items in the Infos list.

I get something like

(sorry the next lot should be a table of start and end times but i cant get it to format in a table layout here)

Start time                       End Time
1549665989.622097       1549666889.6221507
1549665989.6690228      1549666889.6790602
1549665989.8786857      1549666889.8817368
1549665989.8926628      1549666889.9037011

these results seem wrong especially the start times as they should be less than the time index im given.

I think this is a rounding issue, but not sure if its that or my logic.
If it is a rounding issue how should i be doing the testing in LINQ.

any advice appreciated.

It just occurred to me maybe i should multiply each double value by 10000000 to remove the decimals and compare just whole numbers ?
Is that a good idea ?

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Comment: Have you watched the value of starttime? Also what's the type of x.StartTime?

Comment: The value of start time i get from the 3rd party lib is correct i have observed this. The type of x.starttime is double. 
I was expecting items returned from the list where the time index i have tested for is between the start and end times in the list Infos.

Answer (score 2):

Converting a string like `"1549665989.622097"` to double leads to an error due to the precision. In this case the converted double will be `1549665989.6221`.

If precision errors of your doubles are a problem, you should make use of the [decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal) data type:

> The decimal keyword indicates a 128-bit data type. Compared to other floating-point types, the decimal type has more precision and a smaller range, which makes it appropriate for financial and monetary calculations.

[Convert.ToDecimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todecimal?view=netframework-4.7.2) provides the required conversion from a string. The result will be `1549665989.622097` without a precision error.

Comment: How would this precision issue result in returning items where the starttime of the item is > than the time im testing against. Im trying to return items where the startitme is between the x.starttime and x.endtime of the items in the list.

Comment: Please add some sample input and  output to your question.

Answer (score 0):

### Your conversion is inefficient

You do realize that you convert the StartTime string to a double for your `Where`, and a lot of times again for your `OrderBy` don't you: the OrderBy will compare the 1st element with the 2nd, and the 1st with the 3rd, and the 2nd with the 3rd, and the 1st with the 4th and the 2nd with the 4th, and the 3rd with the 4th: you convert your strings to doubles over and over again.

Wouldn't it be more efficient to remember this conversion, and re-use the converted values?

### You convert to the wrong type

As we are converting the 3rd party data anyway, why not convert it to a proper object that represents a point in time: `System.DateTime`?

Write two extension functions of class Info:

```
static class InfoExtensions
{
    public static DateTime StartDateTime(this Info info)
    {
        return info.startTime.ToDateTime();
    }

    public static DateTime EndDateTime(this Info info)
    {
        return info.endTime.ToDateTime();
    }

    private static DateTime ToDateTime(this string date3rdParty)
    {
         // ask from your 3rd party what the value means
        // for instance: seconds since some start epoch time:
        static DateTime epochTime = new DateTime(...)

        double secondsSinceEpochTime = Double.Parse(date3rdParty);
        return epochTime.AddSeconds(secondsSinceEpochTime);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
DateTime startTime = ...
var result = Infos.Select(info => new
{
     StartTime = info.StartTime.StartDatetime(),
     EndTime = info.EndTime.EndDateTime(),

     // select the Info properties you actually plan to use:
     ...

     // or select the complete Info:
     Info = info,
})
.Where(info => info.StartTime <= startTime && startTime <= info.EndTime)
.OrderBy(info => info.StartTime)

// Only if you prefer to throw away your converted StartTime / EndTime:
.Select(info => info.Info);
```

It might be that the precision of your 3rd party time is different than the precision of DateTime, and that you want the ultimate precision. In that case, consider converting their string into `DateTime.Ticks`, and then use this Ticks to create a new DateTime object. Since Ticks are integers, you'll have less trouble with the conversion

### Separation of concerns

You should work more on [separation of concerns](https://blog.ndepend.com/separation-of-concerns-explained/). If you separated the way your 3rdparty represents their idea of dates (some string representation of seconds since some epoch time) from the way you would like to have it (probably System.DateTime), then you wouldn't have this problem.

If you separated their `info` class, from your `info` class, your code will be better maintainable, because you will have only one place where their info properties are translated into your info properties. If in future they add properties that you don't use, you would not notice it. If they decide to change their idea of date, for instance by using a different epoch time, or maybe using a System.DateTime, there will only be one place where you'll have to change your info. Also: if there comes a fourth party info: there is only one place where you'll have to convert.

Separation is efficient: conversion is only done once, no matter how often you use property StartTime. For instance, if in future you want to get all Infos grouped by same Date.

Separation is also easier to test: most of your code will work with your own converted info classes. Only one small piece of code will convert their info to your idea of info. You can test most code using your info class, and their is only one place where you'll have to test the conversion: once you know conversion is Okay, you'll never have to worry about it anymore

Create a class MyNamespace.Info, that has a constructor thirdPartyNamespace.Info:

```
class MyInfo
{
    public DateTime StartTime {get; set;}
    public DateTime EndTime {get; set;}
    ... // other info properties you actually plan to use

    // Constructors:
    public MyInfo() { } // default constructor
    public MyInfo(ThirdParyNameSpace.Info info)
    {
        this.StartTime = info.StartTime.ToDateTime();
        this.EndTime = info.EndTime.ToDateTime();
        ...
    }
}
```

Did you see how easy it is to add support for Info from a fourth party? Or how little change there is if the 3rd party info changes, or if you need more properties (or less)?

Almost all your code can be tested using your local info class. Only one test class is needed to test that the 3rd party info is properly converted to your info.